# Infinite Loop when persisting entity with Event Listeners

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using Symfony 2 with Doctrine 2. I have a `UserListener` ([symfony docs page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html)) that listens to the `PrePersist` & `PreRemove` events for User objects. When Persisting a User, I want to create a `UserInventory` instance for the `User`. `UserInventory` is the owning side of the (uni-directional) association.

However with this setup, I encounter an  infinite loop:

```
class UserListener {

    /**
     * Initializes UserInventory for user with initial number of nets
     */
    public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args) {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $user = $args->getEntity();
        $inventory = new UserInventory();
        $inventory->setUser($user);
        $inventory->setNumNets($this->initialNets);
        $em->persist($inventory); // if I comment out this line, it works but the inventory is not persisted
        $em->flush();
    }

}
```

It might be that `UserInventory` is the owning side of the association thus, it tries to persist the user again resulting in this function called again? How can I fix this?

I want my `UserInventory` to own the association here because its in the "correct" bundle. I have a `UserBundle` but I dont think the Inventory class should be there.

**UPDATE**: [Error/Log](http://pastie.org/3094653)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added a listener for all entites in your application. Of course, when you persist any object, e.g. UserInventory, prePersist will be called again and again.
As the symfony documentation says you can simply do a check:

```
    if ($user instanceof User) {
        $inventory = new UserInventory();
        $inventory->setUser($user);
        $inventory->setNumNets($this->initialNets);
        $em->persist($inventory);
    }
```

Also, I recommend to read about [events](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/events.html) in doctrine2.